# ld warning on xcode 4.5 GM ,

Tags: iphone

When I run my code on developer perview it workes but on GM seed its give following error

```
Ld /Users/GhostMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Retail_Wizard_Solution-eazomrmcxqeysfehcgngulleshls/Build/Intermediates/iFurniture.build/Debug-iphoneos/iFurniture.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/iFurniture normal armv7s
    cd /Volumes/GhostWork/HomeWork/Sachchaudary/furniture-wizard/FurnitureWizard
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Volumes/GraveYard/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/GraveYard/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Volumes/GraveYard/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Volumes/GraveYard/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/GhostMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Retail_Wizard_Solution-eazomrmcxqeysfehcgngulleshls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Volumes/GhostWork/HomeWork/Sachchaudary/furniture-wizard/FurnitureWizard/../OpenSSL/lib -F/Users/GhostMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Retail_Wizard_Solution-eazomrmcxqeysfehcgngulleshls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/GhostMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Retail_Wizard_Solution-eazomrmcxqeysfehcgngulleshls/Build/Intermediates/iFurniture.build/Debug-iphoneos/iFurniture.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/iFurniture.LinkFileList -dead_strip -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -lz -lTBXML-iOS -lsqlite3 -lFMDB -lcrypto -lssl -lxml2 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework ExternalAccessory -framework CFNetwork -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework MessageUI -framework CoreText -lHTTPServer -framework CoreData -lAshleyWebservice -lCommon -lDDXML -lFTPServer -lTapkuLibrary -lWizardScanner -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/GhostMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Retail_Wizard_Solution-eazomrmcxqeysfehcgngulleshls/Build/Intermediates/iFurniture.build/Debug-iphoneos/iFurniture.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/iFurniture

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/GhostMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Retail_Wizard_Solution-eazomrmcxqeysfehcgngulleshls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTBXML-iOS.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/GhostMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Retail_Wizard_Solution-eazomrmcxqeysfehcgngulleshls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTBXML-iOS.a
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Volumes/GhostWork/HomeWork/Sachchaudary/furniture-wizard/OpenSSL/lib/libcrypto.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You're linking to a static library which was built for the simulator or older devices (i386/x86_64 or armv6, respectively). Link to another library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Armv7s refers to the iPhone5 hardware. As of Xcode 4.5 GM this is a default Architecture. If you have access to the source of the library, you should add the architecture armv7s in `Target -> Architectures`.

If you can't rebuild the library, just remove armv7s from the Architectures and Valid Architectures in your project's target settings and any subprojects you have as well.

You could also try the approach [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/09/hacking-up-an-armv7s-library/), however, given that the directory in your question is in a homework directory, I assume you won't be submitting to the app store so it is fine to leave out armv7s from your architectures.